# How to search in the system path for a file?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have `x.dll` in some folder which is part of the system path. And I also have some another file `x.zzz` in the same folder and this is not an executable.

From a C++ program, I want to search for `x.zzz` without loading the `x.dll`. But I want this to work exactly like the `LoadLibrary` function. i.e, it should go in the same order of search as the `LoadLibrary`.

Is this possible?

PS : 
I checked `SearchPath()` function, but there is a remark in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which says this shouldn't be used for this purpose.

> The SearchPath function is not recommended as a method of locating a .dll file if the
>       intended use of the output is in a call to the LoadLibrary function. This can result
>       in locating the wrong .dll file because the search order of the SearchPath function 
>       differs from the search order used by the LoadLibrary function. If you need to locate 
>       and load a .dll file, use the LoadLibrary function.

Comment: I suspect that there is no good answer to the question you asked. What is your actual underlying problem?

Comment: @David: The x.zzz contains some auxiliary information that we use to implement reflection. So, we need to open this file and check for the existence of some classes here. Yes, it looks like there is no straightforward way to achieve this. We will find some dirty way to achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: Rather than using a dirty way to do this, perhaps you might implement a better solution

Comment: Yes. What I was describing 'dirty' is to write a long routine myself with findfiles etc or something like that.... :)

Comment: Our solution to this exact problem was to emulate the behaviour of LoadLibrary with a series of low level calls (FIndFirstFile as I remember). Nothing else did it quite right.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using any built in function is that they'll be specifically looking for executables or dlls.  I'd say your best bet is to actually parse the path variable and iterate through the directories manually.  This can be done with C functions for directory iteration.  The following should work on most platforms.

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
...
std::string findInPath(const std::string &key, char delim = ';');
std::string findInDir(const std::string &key, const std::string &dir);
...
std::string findInDir(const std::string &key, const std::string &directory)
{
  DIR *dir = opendir(directory.c_str());
  if(!dir)
    return "";

  dirent *dirEntry;
  while(dirEntry = readdir(dir))
  {
    if(key == dirEntry->d_name) // Found!
      return directory+'/'+key;
  }
  return "";
}

std::string findInPath(const std::string &key, char delim)
{
  std::string path(std::getenv("PATH"));
  size_t posPrev = -1;
  size_t posCur;
  while((posCur = path.find(delim, posPrev+1)) != std::string::npos)
  {
    // Locate the next directory in the path
    std::string pathCurrent = path.substr(posPrev+1, posCur-posPrev-1);

    // Search the current directory
    std::string found = findInDir(key, pathCurrent);
    if(!found.empty())
      return found;

    posPrev = posCur;
  }

  // Locate the last directory in the path
  std::string pathCurrent = path.substr(posPrev+1, path.size()-posPrev-1);

  // Search the current directory
  std::string found = findInDir(key, pathCurrent);
  if(!found.empty())
    return found;

  return "";
}
```

Comment: LoadLibrary has a lot more search logic than just looking in PATH.

Answer (score 1):

How about using LoadLibraryEx() with flag LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE?

From the [LoadLibraryEx documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> If this value is used, the system maps the file into the process's virtual address space as an image file. However, the loader does not load the static imports or perform the other usual initialization steps. Use this flag when you want to load a DLL only to extract messages or resources from it.

I realize you said "without loading"... but using this technique would keep the .dll's functions and variables from polluting your namespaces, etc.  If you have a performance requirement, or some other specific reason to specify "without loading", do expand on that.

Comment: I had seen this before and ruled out because of the loading overhead. But looks like this is as far as I can get. I will accept this if nothing else comes out in another half an hour.

Comment: I don't think this will work unless the file is a PE file. And even if it did, how would you find out the file name? Call `GetModuleFileName`?!

Comment: If you use `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE`, "you cannot call functions **like GetModuleFileName**, GetModuleHandle or GetProcAddress with this DLL".  So you would have to find another way to retrieve the filename associated with the handle of the loaded DLL.

Comment: Fair enough, I've edited the answer to not even mention _AS_DATAFILE.